# How to get a text in a fixed position like the "background-attachment: fixed"?

Tags: html, text, fixed

I'm making a one-page website which would contain 5 different images each containing a different text, and based on the "background-attachment: fixed", I was wondering if it were possible to have the text in a fixed position. If yes, what is the code for it?

```css
.img{
background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
   width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
    margin: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  text-align: center;
    min-width: 520px;
  max-width: 520px;
}

.img1{
  background-image: url();
}

.img2{
background-image: url();
}
```

```html
<div class="img img1">
    <div class="text">
<p>...</p>
  </div></div>
<div class="img img2">
<div class="text">
<p>....</p>
</div></div>
```

Comment: `position:fixed`

Comment: Thank you.
One problem is when I go to the next image, the paragraph remains the same, and as I have 5 different images each containing a different paragraph, I was hoping that the paragraph would switch to the one meant for each image when I go up or down. Do you know what code to use to do that?